# Express routing with params filter coming from emberJs

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js

I have a problem to make the route for this url :

`http://localhost:3000/api/tests?filter%5Bcodeid%5D=eeee`

At the moment i tried this:

**In the server**

```
app.route('/api/tests?filter[codeid]=:param')
  .get((req, res) => {
    console.log('It works');
    res.status(200).send({
      msg: 'It works'
    });
  });
```

**In the front**

```
this.store.query('test', { filter: { codeid: code } })
    .then(test => {
      if(test.get('firstObject')){
        console.log(test.get('firstObject').get('id'));
        console.log('exist');
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

But when I test my server with postman I have this result:

`Cannot GET /api/tests?filter%5Bcodeid%5D=eeee`

Someone has any idea of how manage this ?

**Edit:**

I use the json-api

https://github.com/ethanresnick/json-api

And this is my server file with all my routes:

https://github.com/DidelotK/QcmServerEmber/blob/Express_problem_stack/app/controller/express-server.js

Comment: Binding path is `/api/tests`, `?filter%5Bcodeid%5D=eeee` is request params. You can bind `/api/test/filter-:codeid`.

Comment: Same things it does not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution of my problem, here:

https://github.com/ethanresnick/json-api/issues/64

So the error was in ember, and to make it works, I changed this:

```
this.store.query('test', { filter: { codeid: code } })
.then(test => {
  if(test.get('firstObject')){
    console.log(test.get('firstObject').get('id'));
    console.log('exist');
  }
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

To this:

```
this.store.query('test', { filter: { simple { codeid: code } } })
.then(test => {
  if(test.get('firstObject')){
    console.log(test.get('firstObject').get('id'));
    console.log('exist');
  }
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What your are trying to do is called express query, [Express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query), so your route should not have that extra parameters ,it should look something like this

```
app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.status(200).json(req.query);    
});
```

And when u send request for that route than..

> http://localhost:3000/test?a=5&b=3

Answer (score -1):

Try code below

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({extended: false})); // to provide req.params.param

app.route('/test')
  .get((req, res) => {
    console.log('It works');
    res.status(200).json({ // I think you doesn't want send text
      msg: 'It works'
    });
  });

app.route('/test/filter[codeid]=:param')
  .get((req, res) => {
    console.log('It works', req.params.param);
    res.status(200).send({
      msg: 'It works',
      code: req.params.param
    });
  });

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: Same things the filter does not works, i have only the it works